# How do I tell my application which resx file to use when it is passed a culture it doesn't understand? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, default, culture, resx

Subject says it all.  I have Resources.en-US.resx, Resources.de-DE.resx, etc.  I don't ever want the basic Resources.resx file to be referenced.  If someone passes me a language that I don't have a resx for I want it to drop back and use Resources.en-US.resx.   Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.neutralresourceslanguageattribute.aspx):

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US" , UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```